# Xamarin Forms "open file with" from specific path

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to open a file from specific path with default external installed application ,

EX: I have the following path

```
@"storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180502_162205.jpg"
```

In C# we use

```
Process.Start("IMG_20180502_162205.jpg", @"storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180502_162205.jpg");
```

but in Xamarin i couldn't find any code specific for Xamarin Forms to do this task

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64441/xamarin-forms-display-image-in-default-gallery-application

Comment: Do you find a solution?